# SSAS Relationship Slowly Changing Dimension

Tags: sql, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have this structure in my Data Warehouse

```
DimCustomer
   -id  (pk)
   -Name
   -Country
   -datestart
   -dateend

FactBalance
   -idCustomer (pk) (fk [DimCustomer.id])
   -idTime (pk) (fk [DimDate.DateSK])
   -Balance
```

The Customer Dimension has multiple rows for when the country changes, and the FactBalance has multiple rows for every day over a period of time.

Here is some example data:

```
DimCustomer

1  JoeBloggs England  2012-01-01   2012-01-04
2  JoeBloggs France   2012-01-05   NULL

FactBalance

1  20120101 12334.0
1  20120102 12334.0
1  20120103 12334.0
1  20120104 12334.0
2  20120105 12334.0
2  20120106 12334.0
```

The problem I'm having is that when I view my cube in the browser and use DimCustomer.Country and FactBalance.Balance (which has aggregation set to LastNonNull) it shows two results

```
 England  12334.0
 France   12334.0
```

It is obviously getting the last non null for each of those customer entries in the SCD but how do I set up the dimension so that it only shows the last for the whole customer?

Comment: Is there a foreign key relationship?  If so, what field references what?

Comment: Apologies, yes there are. I have added them in. I realised that the idCustomer field was a bit confusing so I changed it to Name

Answer (score 0):

I would add the Business Key (I think it's Name in your example) to the Fact (I would add it as a column in the Fact table, or you could go via a SQL View).

Then I would build an alternative version of the Customer dimension that only shows the current records and uses the Business Key as it's key.

Finally I would add the new dimension to the cube and relate it to the Fact using the Business Key.